# How do i add half hexagons on either side of my screen?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a website with HTML, CSS, and JS.In which JavaScript determines the browser's dimensions and then adds the hexagon-div to a container to create the **Honeycomb Hexagon Grid** over the entire page. I discovered that there are empty spots in the corners where a whole hexagon cannot fit, and I don't want that.

Half hexagons should be placed there to fill the voids.
Furthermore, I have svg code for half hexagons:

HALF LEFT HEXAGON:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 116" width="50" height="116">
  <polygon points="50,0 50,115.48 0,86.61 0,28.87" fill="#28282B"/>
</svg>
```

HALF RIGHT HEXAGON:

```
<svg viewBox="50 0 50 116" width="50" height="116">
  <polygon points="50,0 100,28.87 100,86.61 50,115.48" fill="#28282B"/>
</svg>
```

```js
const hexagonWidth = 100;
const hexagonHeight = 115.48;
const rowHeight = 125;
const numRows = 12;
const numCols = 19;

const container = document.getElementById("hexagons");

for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");

    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        row.classList.add("row-moved");
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        const hexagon = document.createElement("div");
        hexagon.classList.add("hexagon");

        hexagon.style.width = hexagonWidth + "px";
        hexagon.style.height = hexagonHeight + "px";
        hexagon.style.margin = "5.5px 2px";

        const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svg.setAttribute("height", rowHeight);

        const polygon1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
        polygon1.setAttribute("points", "50,0 100,28.87 100,86.61 50,115.48 0,86.61 0,28.87");
        polygon1.setAttribute("fill", "#28282B");

        const polygon2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
        polygon2.setAttribute("points", "50,0 100,28.87 100,86.61 50,115.48");
        polygon2.setAttribute("fill", "#28282B");

        svg.appendChild(polygon1);
        svg.appendChild(polygon2);
        hexagon.appendChild(svg);
        row.appendChild(hexagon);
    }

    container.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #171717;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 125px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-left: -33px;
}

.row .hexagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 115.48px;
    margin: 5.5px 2px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.row .hexagon:hover polygon {
    fill: #3fff3c;
}

.row.row-moved {
    margin-left: 19px;
}

.row .hexagon svg polygon {
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.row .hexagon svg polygon:hover {
    fill: #3fff3c;
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagons"></div>
```

Comment: Is it going to be used at a background on the page or will it have some function (like tils for a game)?

Comment: Maybe take inspiration from this: https://codepen.io/d3nis031/pen/QWyeNYx and use `divs` with pseudo-classes and `clip-path` instead of svg?

Answer (score 0):

In this example I just cut off part of the hex that needs to be half. Its is cut off by the edge of the SVG and I also use a mask (#m1) that hides 1 unit in each side.

The entire SVG scales to the width of the page now that I only set a viewBox on the SVG. As the example is now 4 hex fit in the width. If you need more or less the viewBox can be changed together with the number of hex in a row.

```css
body {
  background: #171717;
}

#hex:hover {
  fill: #3fff3c;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 108 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect x="1" width="106" height="100" fill="white" />
    </mask>
    <symbol id="hex" viewBox="0 0 52 60" width="26" height="30" fill="#28282B">
      <rect width="30" height="30" transform="translate(0 15) rotate(-30) skewX(30)" />
      <rect y="15" width="52" height="30" />
      <rect width="30" height="30" transform="translate(0 45) rotate(-60) skewY(30)" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#m1)">
    <g transform="translate(1 0)">
      <use href="#hex" />
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(27 0)"/>
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(54 0)"/>
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(81 0)"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-12.5 23.5)">
      <use href="#hex" />
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(27 0)"/>
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(54 0)"/>
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(81 0)"/>
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(108 0)"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(1 47)">
      <use href="#hex" />
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(27 0)"/>
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(54 0)"/>
      <use href="#hex" transform="translate(81 0)"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```